# Precompile with compression in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compression, development-environment

I'd like to run the task

assets:precompile

with compression in development environment.

I've set

```
config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier

config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

in development.rb.

But compression with assets:precompile only seems to work in production mode, is that right?

Michael Kastner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file compress in rails try this following method it will work exactly

My config/environments/development.rb has this, which I interpret the rails guide to mean that assets should be compiled into one file, but not compressed:

`config.assets.compress = false

config.assets.compile = true

config.assets.digest = false

config.assets.debug = false`

Try to add debug: false to your include/link-tags

It work means please

`{# in views/layouts/application.html.haml (or .erb, then use <%= %>)}
= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", debug: false
= javascript_include_tag "application", debug: false`

No need to restart app! I hope you didn't forget to do it after you had changed your development.rb ;-).

Comment: Great, simply setting

config.assets.debug = true

did it. It was always there, right in front of me.

Thanks a lot.